# strategy setup without calc on every tick

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i have my strategy setup as follows

Set on the 1 minute chart

```
strategy(title="Support BOT ALERTS ALL EXCHANGES ", 
 overlay=true , 
 format=format.price, 
 pyramiding = 0,
 initial_capital = 500,
 calc_on_every_tick = false,
 calc_on_order_fills = true,
 process_orders_on_close = false,
 default_qty_type = strategy.cash,
 default_qty_value = 500,
 commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, 
 commission_value = 0.1, 
 max_labels_count = 500,
 use_bar_magnifier = true)

BuySignal_tf1  =    (buy settings) and barstate.isconfirmed
f_Buy_TF2() =>    [buys settings2]

[BuySignaltf2]      = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', f_buy_TF2(),  barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on)

if BuySignal_tf1 and BuySignaltf2 and strategy.position_size==0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long )
```

Question is - because  calc_on_every_tick is false does that mean that if i reference higher timeframes it will only trigger the alert at the close of each higher timeframe bar that is referenced or does the calc_on_every_tick only apply to the timeframe that the alert is set on.

During backtesting it works fine but i dont want to only send an alert once the highest timeframe bar referenced closes, in some cases i am referncing the 4 hr timeframe.

Just wanted to ask the question before i go setting all my alerts and then realise they will only trigger at the close of the highest timeframe requested

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `calc_on_every_tick` to `false` (which is the default value), your script will be executed on bar close. This will refer to your chart's timeframe.